# Ubuntu 14 wifi not working

Tags: wireless, virtualbox, software-center

I have a problem with wireless connection on ubuntu 14.04. I guess I should install some drivers but still can't figure it out. Some types and responses from terminal:

```
lspci | grep Network
```

I get empty message.

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

I get

```
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

I typed `bcm` in software center and downloaded the driver but it doesn't appear in `Software & Updates` in system settings. Any ideas how to get it working?

EDIT:
`lspci -nn | grep 0280` Empty result. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` also empty result. Here's the result of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

If this is an info here, I run ubuntu on virtualbox on windows 7.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Thanks.

Comment: Better this command  "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Ubuntu in Virtualbox, then you do not need to setup wireless connections there. It will use host system connection.
Guest system does not directly use network hardware, unless it is a USB dongle, which you passed through to the guest system.

Comment: thx it's actually working, God knows why. I wouldn't have posted this if it worked earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the "linux-firmware-nonfree" by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

And then reboot. (it's worked for me)

Comment: The package 'linux-firmware-nonfree` is deprecated.